# Show that the d point is not continious. (Point-set topology)

Tags: general-topology

$X = ${$a,b,c,d$} and $Y =$ {$x,y,z,w$}
There are two topologies
$T_1=$ {$\phi$, $X$, {$a$}, {$a,b$}, {$a,b,c$}}
$T_2 =$ {$\phi$, $Y$, {$y$}, {$y,z,w$}}
For $(X,T_1)$ and $(Y,T_2)$ topological spaces there is a $g$ function.
${a}$ $\mapsto$ ${y}$,
${b}$ $\mapsto$ ${y}$,
${c}$ $\mapsto$ ${w}$,
${d}$ $\mapsto ${z}$   (sorry i couldn't draw the diagram.)
Question: Show that the d point is not continious.

Solution: On my solutions I always find it continious but on the lecture i watch on the youtube the guy says it not continious can you check my solution and say what am I doing wrong.

My solution:
$g(d)=z \in U$ and $U \in T_2$
We should find our open set $U$'s which $U$ can be
$U=${$y,z,w$} or $U=Y$
Now we have to find a V that inludes {d} on T1 topology and if $F(V) \subseteq U$ for all the $U$'s then $d$ is continious.

Lets say $V=X$
$g(X)=${$y,z,w$}$\subseteq U$ so the {d} is continious.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Points aren't continuous:  functions are.  Do you mean that $g$ is not continuous at $d$?

Comment: @Randall yes sorry I did not write it well. g is not continious at point d.

Comment: You are not wrong. $g$ IS continuous at $d$.